# Is there a way to write an "empty field"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, formatting, markdown

It is quite common (especially in the `single-word-request` tag) to want an "empty field" for example phrases:

> *"Having children of my own* __*_*__*_*__ *me"*

Since markdown uses underscores for formatting, it has a tendency to eat up or mess with underscores. However, as you can see, if you use enough underscores, a few will still get through, but the result is a bit "choppy".

*I wasn't sure which tags to use:* is there any way around this problem (`discussion`), or is it possible to change the parser to treat a string of 3+ underscores as plaintext instead of trying to format it (`feature-request`)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The best solution is to *escape* the underscore with the backslash. Using a backslash forces the following character to be used literally rather than as part of Markdown formatting:

`\_\_\_\_\_\_`
______

You could also use code formatting (with backticks), which is always literal, but that also adds a grey background which may not be universally liked.

`______`

Click [`Edit`](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/4477/edit) below to see how this post is formatted. If you can't do that, here's a picture:

[image: Image of edit window]

Comment: The source can't be viewed: _"Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites."_

Comment: I didn't realise that. I've added a picture.

Comment: Oh, for Pete's sake. This is why I only use HTML when I write questions and answers. Markdown assumes too many things about too many things.

Comment: I thought the use of backticks for emphasis was discouraged on SE sites

Comment: @toryan It is, which is why I mentioned "may not be universally liked". In **this** case, it's not emphasis, it's providing a space which looks like a form field. Backslashes are definitely better.

Answer (score 3):

The gray box produced by `<code>` tags / backticks might even be turned into an advantage:

```
"Having children of my own <code>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</code> me"
```

- "Having children of my own             me"

or, perhaps more simply:

```
"Having children of my own `...........` me"
```

- "Having children of my own `...........` me"

(Somehow, the dots look a lot nicer than underscores in combination with the box, at least IMO.)

Yes, I realize that this is kind of abusing the markup, but honestly, how often do you see *real* code on ELU?

Comment: I'm a bit disturbed that `<code>` doesn't stop entities from being interpreted. Is that not a bug?

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I'm pretty sure it's deliberate: backticks do disable entities, but HTML tags like `<code>` don't.

Comment: Indeed, not a bug but a feature, IMO.  Over on StackOverflow, <code> tags are often the only way to demonstrate exactly the content in question.

Answer (score -1):

The closest solution I have found is using [ASCII character 242](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/underline-underscore-ascii-code-242.html) since it isn't parsed by Markdown, but in some fonts, it shows up as double underscores:

> *"Having children of my own ‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗ me"*

Comment: That's not an ASCII character; it's an ["extended ASCII"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) character that only has the value 242 on Windows machines.  Its proper (i.e., Unicode) value is U+2017.